# Would falsely claiming W-4 exempt status?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding

I have ~60K coming from my employer as supplemental wages

If I get this in lump sum, the tax withheld would be around 40%. My usual tax rate is about 25%. I know I would get much of that extra tax back, but I would like to use some it towards down payment of a house.

So, the question is, can I (falsely) claim exempt on my W-4; then pay appropriate tax when I file a return?

Would this create problems with the IRS?

Comment: Look up penalties for underpayment of tax.

Comment: Are you saying the total tax, federal, state, FICA, will total 40%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

W4 has usually no effect on lump-sum payments. These are usually (unless the employer is feeling extremely masochistic) are under flat 25% withholding rate rule. So changing the W4 will likely have no effect. Confirm with your employer if they're using the flat withholding rate or actually doing the math with the regular allowances, which I doubt they'd do.

To the point, claiming you're exempt when you're not *is* fraudulent. You can achieve the result you want by increasing the allowances, instead.

Comment: Yes, just ask since it will probably not be 40%.. I have had situations where the company will ask me whether I would prefer the flat 25% or an additional withholding. Note that a large tax bill due at the end of the year from improper withholding may raise red flags for audit and will likely incur penalties.

Comment: I've never once had a lump payment receive the 25% flat withholding.

Comment: They may use a flat 25% method, but don't have to. Perhaps some employers feel they are doing you a favor by using the aggregate method and estimating tax from your accumulated pay and your W4 allowances. This may especially be the case if you are in a high earning bracket since it is assumed that you will owe more than 25%.

Comment: @quid I've never once seen anything but flat withholding... I guess YMMV, either way saying you're exempt when you're not can only land you in trouble.

Comment: @quid - I've seen the same, any check that wasn't semi-monthly salary was subject to 25%. The best trick I had was to bump 401(k) withholding just before the check was cut. But whatever was left still had that 25%.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @quid - Same here. My employer wants to use regular tax rate. I claimed more allowance based on the worksheet (still a large extra withholding than for my annual tax bracket). Uncle Sam got a large tax free loan from me.

Comment: @Sang, the best I was ever able to do was use a quarterly frequency table rather than the per pay period frequency to estimate the annual amount based on the check.  That helped.  But your employer/payroll vendor may not be so flexible.